# VB.Net : Writing SQL Table field into Link Label Parent Control

Tags: vb.net

I have a bunch of link label controls stored in SQL. I have figured out how to pull them and create the link label but when I try to write the lnk.Parent Control I get "Unable to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.windows.forms.control'. Is there a way to convert this?

```
Private Sub CreateLinkLabel(Lnk_DT As DataTable)
    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In Lnk_DT.Rows
            lnk = New LinkLabel
            lnk.Name = row("FLD_LnkName").ToString
            lnk.Text = row("FLD_LnkName").ToString
            lnk.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            lnk.Location = New Point(20, i)
            lnk.Parent = row("FLD_LnkPanel")
            lnk.Tag = row("Fld_LnkTag").ToString
            lnk.AutoSize = True
            AddHandler lnk.LinkClicked, AddressOf lnk_LinkClicked
            i = i + 25
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: The Parent property should be assigned to a Form object (or other container control) so I suppose the you should write _lnk.Parent = Me_ but in any case the correct way to add controls to a container is through the Add method of the Controls control collection

Comment: What is the content of the field _row("FLD_LnkPanel")_?

Comment: @Steve: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: The panel name that the link goes in.

Answer (score 0):

The Parent property should be assigned to a Form object (or other container control) so I suppose that you should write `lnk.Parent = Me` but in any case the correct way to add controls to a container is through the Add method of the Controls control collection.

For example, to add the newly created label to the current form, you write this inside your loop

```
 Me.Controls.Add(lnk)
```

Looking at your code it seems that the field `row("FLD_LnkPanel")` is the name of a Panel control on your form. If you want to add the created label to this panel then you should write

```
Private Sub CreateLinkLabel(Lnk_DT As DataTable)
    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In Lnk_DT.Rows
            ' Get the panel name '
            Dim panelName = row("FLD_LnkPanel")

            ' Search the panel between the Form controls'
            Dim panel = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
                                   .FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = panelName)
            ' If you got it, then proceed with the label creation
            if panel IsNot Nothing Then
                lnk = New LinkLabel
                lnk.Name = row("FLD_LnkName").ToString
                lnk.Text = row("FLD_LnkName").ToString
                lnk.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
                lnk.Location = New Point(20, i)
               ' lnk.Parent = row("FLD_LnkPanel")'
                lnk.Tag = row("Fld_LnkTag").ToString
                lnk.AutoSize = True
                AddHandler lnk.LinkClicked, AddressOf lnk_LinkClicked
                i = i + 25

                ' Add the label to the panel child controls
                panel.Controls.Add(lnk)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is Panel Then
        If c.Name = row("FLD_LnkPanel") Then
            lnk.Parent = c
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this:

```
Private Sub CreateUIControls(Lnk_DT As DataTable)    
        For Each row As DataRow In Lnk_DT.Rows
            Dim isPanelNew As Boolean
            Dim pnl As Panel = GetPanel(row, isPanelNew)
            CreateLink(row, pnl)

            If isPanelNew Then
                pnl.Location = New Point(10, 20) ' whatever logic
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetPanel(item As DataRow, ByRef isNew As Boolean) As Panel
        isNew = False

        Dim pnlItem As Panel = Nothing
        Dim pnlName As String = item.Field(Of String)("FLD_LnkPanel")

        ' check if panel already exists on form.
        Dim pnl As Panel = (From p In Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
                            Where p.Name = pnlName
                            Select p).SingleOrDefault()

        If pnl Is Nothing Then
            pnlItem = New Panel
            pnlItem.Width = 200 ' whatever logic
            isNew = True
        Else
            pnlItem = pnl
        End If

        Return pnlItem
    End Function

    Private Sub CreateLink(item As DataRow, parentControl As Panel)
        ' get how many links are in the panel. 
        Dim linksCount = parentControl.Controls.OfType(Of LinkLabel).Count()
        Dim lnk As New LinkLabel

        With lnk
            .Name = item.Field(Of String)("FLD_LnkName")
            .Text = item.Field(Of String)("FLD_LnkName")
            .Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
            .Tag = item.Field(Of String)("Fld_LnkTag")
            .AutoSize = True

            ' increase panel height to fit the new link.
            parentControl.Height = ((linksCount + 1) * 25) + 10
            .Parent = parentControl

            .Location = New Point(20, (linksCount * 25) + 3)
            AddHandler .LinkClicked, AddressOf lnk_LinkClicked
        End With
    End Sub
```